# Print assembly output of compiled d program like asm.dlang.org

Tags: assembly, d

How to replicate the functionality of http://asm.dlang.org/ locally?

How can I print the assembly output of a compiled code-snippet written in d language?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to disassemble the compiled object file or final binary. On linux, you can use `objdump` and on Windows, Digital Mars sells an `obj2asm` utility.

Comment: I was able to install `gobjdump` on mac using `brew install binutils`, then use it like this: `gobjdump -d answer.o | less`. This gives somewhat similar results, except that it doesn't work for code snippets, and the used imported functions are also displayed. Any chance that the source-code of asm.dlang.org is available?

Comment: I don't know about the source of asm.dlang.org but I'm sure it just filters the output of objdump. You can grep for a particular function name.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use `disassemble <function>` command in gdb - it allows for more interactive investigation compared to objdump. Quite likely, "your favorite debugger name" will have something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using LDC as your D compiler then you can specify command line option `-output-s` to produce assembly output.

Comment: works! Same verbosity, but at least I have a compiled LDC now. :)